# Обработка сообщения о рисовании(WM_PAINT) в GLFW

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

Есть ли возможность в GLFW обработать сообщение WM_PAINT? Если да, то как? Нужно мне это для того, чтобы рисовать не в цикле, а по получению сообщения. Например, если увеличивать размер окна, то появляются чёрные края на изображении и пропадают они только когда отпустишь левую кнопку мышки, т.е. когда закончишь менять размер окна. При отрисовки по сообщению этого не происходит.

Comment: Если вы всё равно завязываетесь на Windows, смысл в использовании GLFW? Создать окно и инициализировать контекст OpenL легко можно и без библиотеки-посредника.